# Christian science fiction novel with Han Solo type character

Tags: story-identification, novel, christian

I'm trying to track down a science fiction novel that features a Christian protagonist, perhaps similar to Han Solo, who pilots a ship on the space lanes while reading the Gospel.

I'm sure I came across this book 10-15 years ago, although the book itself was likely published earlier, but can't recall the title or author.

Comment: Was there a novel version of Marjoe Gortner's *Starcrash*?

Comment: @ZeissIkon No, I don't think so.

Comment: You might look at [this list](https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/33985.Christian_Science_Fiction) and see if any of the covers jump out at you.